# Looking for word (like exceed) that says you ignore an annoying thing because person is very good at something else and that matters the most

Tags: word-request

What's the word for saying: he/she has many good qualities, so that to you it makes a minor annoying behaviour so small when compared overall. For example,

Her caring attitude ......, this minor thing. I am happy with her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...matters more than...","...is more important than...", or in 1 word: "overshadows" or "outweighs". And many, many more, available in [a thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com)

"Exceeds" probably isn't *exactly* the word you want, because it only means the first item is bigger, greater or more copious or numerous than the other item. It wouldn't be about the importance of the 2 things unless you explicitly named the property of importance. Something like:

"Her caring attitude *exceeds in importance* this minor thing."

And that sounds a little bit wordy and clumsy, to me anyway.